# The right way of showing the greeting message in telegram chat

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegraf

The question here regarding showing the Greeting message in chat:

````
bot.on('new_chat_members', (ctx) => {

console.log(ctx.message.new_chat_members) // console log works well giving out the right array // the next console log doesn't work and makes me cofused

console.log(ctx.message.new_chat_members.username) // log is undefined

// As far as I understood that line should work... but it's not.

bot.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, "Welcome to the official Chat @" + ctx.message.new_chat_members.username); })```
````

Answer (score 0):

Telegram passes new members inside an array whether it's one member or more.

`ctx.message.new_chat_members`

This is an array, you should iterate through each user in the array and then log their username.

so:

```js
for (const user of ctx.message.new_chat_members) {
    console.log(user.username)
}
```